# Cómo enviar un ArrayList del cliente al servidor usando UDP?

Tags: java

Quiero enviar una lista de números al servidor para que este al leerlos efectúe las operaciones correspondientes y devuelva el resultado de las mismas al cliente. Luego volverá a pedir números al cliente y de nuevo le devolverá el resultado correspondiente, repitiéndose el proceso hasta que el cliente introduzca un *, entonces ahí se cerraría conexión con el servidor. Tengo que hacerlo obligatoriamente utilizando protocolo UDP.

El problema es que al mandar los números por lo visto al servidor no le llegan dichos números y no hace nada. Cuando ejecuto el programa me pide los 4 números, los introduzco y ahí es donde se queda parado, el servidor no devuelve ningún resultado. Para guardar los números he utilizado el ArrayList numeros... el problema es el proceso para empaquetar esa lista de números en bytes, mandarlo al servidor y que este lo decodifique y lea esos números, ahí por lo visto no le llega la información al servidor. Soy un novato en esto de conexiones TCP/UDP, seguro que me habré equivocado pero no sé como solucionarlo, espero podáis orientarme un poco, porque estoy más perdido que un pulpo en un garaje.

El código del servidor es es:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9886);
        byte[] infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
        byte[] infoEnviada = new byte[1024];
        byte[] paquete = new byte[1024];
        String cadena;
        List list;
        int n1,n2,n3,n4;
        int res;
        String num;
        String num1,num2,num3,num4;
        String x;


        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");            
            infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket paqRecibido = new DatagramPacket(infoRecibida, infoRecibida.length);
            serverSocket.receive(paqRecibido);            


         // IP y puerto desde donde se manda mensaje

            InetAddress IPOrigen = paqRecibido.getAddress();
            int puerto = paqRecibido.getPort();


            //Estas dos lineas supuestamente serían para poder leer el arraylist enviado desde el cliente, aunque igual estoy equivocado

            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(infoRecibida));
            ArrayList<Integer> numeros = (ArrayList<Integer>)inputStream.readObject();

            n1 = numeros.get(0);
            n2 = numeros.get(1);
            n3 = numeros.get(2);
            n4 = numeros.get(3);

            num1= Integer.toString(n1);
            num2= Integer.toString(n2);
            num3= Integer.toString(n3);
            num4= Integer.toString(n4);


            // Si alguno de los números introducidos es * 
            // envío "x" al cliente para que este se cierre, posteriormente sale del bucle y se cierra también el servidor

            if (num1=="*"||num2=="*"||num3=="*"||num4=="*") {
                x = "x";
                paquete = x.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket paqueteFinal = new DatagramPacket(paquete, paquete.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
                break;
            }


            //Hago las operaciones, el resultado lo paso a cadena y luego a bytes, para ser enviado al cliente

            res=(n1+n2)*n3-n4;
            num = Integer.toString(res);                      
            infoEnviada=num.getBytes();



            // ENVIO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE

            DatagramPacket paqEnviado = new DatagramPacket(infoEnviada, infoEnviada.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
            serverSocket.send(paqEnviado);

        } //Fin While


        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Socket cerrado...");

    }

}
```

Y el del Cliente este

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String cadena;      
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();


        //para recibir y enviar datos 

        byte[] datosEnviados = new byte[1024];
        byte[] datosRecibidos = new byte[1024];


        InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getByName(...); //En el paréntesis iría el número de ip del servidor adonde quiero mandarlo
        int puerto = 6000;

        ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

        while(true) {

            //Rellenamos ArrayList numeros

            for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
                System.out.println("Introduce un mensaje: ");
                cadena = in.readLine();
                numeros.add(Integer.parseInt(cadena));          
            }


            //Empaquetamos ArrayList en bytes para poder enviarlo al servidor

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(numeros);
            byte[] listData = out.toByteArray();


            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(listData, listData.length, IPServidor, puerto);
            clientSocket.send(envio);
            outputStream.close();


            //recibimos respuesta del servidor

            DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(datosRecibidos, datosRecibidos.length);
            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");
            clientSocket.receive(recibo);
            String numero = new String(recibo.getData()); 

            //Si el dato que devuelve el servidor es "x", salimos del bucle y se cierra el cliente       
            if (numero.equals("x")) { 
                break;           
            }        
            System.out.println("\t Datos: " + numero);      

        } //Fin While

        clientSocket.close(); //Cerramos cliente
    }

}
```

Comment: No estoy del todo seguro, pero prueba a  meter el `clientSocket.receive(recibo)` antes de que se cree el objeto `envió`

Comment: También seria mas fácil si concatenas por comas el array en un String  "12,14,1,3" y al recibirlo en el servidor lo partes con split.

Comment: Roberto Moran, pues sí lo he pensado, pero esa es la opción fácil y me satisface más lograrlo metiendo los números uno por uno. Además creo que el ejercicio me lo pide así, o sea como tal y como dices tú no me valdría.

Comment: Cadeq que meta clientSocket.receive(recibo) antes de crear el objeto envio? Pues no me tiene mucho sentido eso, cómo puedo recibir la respuesta del servidor si aún no le he enviado ningún dato? De todas formas, ya lo probé en el código y no funciona. Pero me dio curiosidad saber por qué te pareció que podía funcionar, porque la lógica no se la veo. Sin ánimo de ofender eh.

Comment: Perdona Pico, me equivoque de linea, es `outputStream.close();` el de poner fuera. Como tu dices, lo otro no tiene ningún sentido. Es mas que nada si por no haber cerrado el Stream antes de usarlo, este no se manda correctamente.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Cuando lo ejecuto me pide por consola 4 números, una vez que los he metido le doy a intro y me sale  "Esperando datagrama..." y ahí se queda parado.. Es decir, me está ejecutando el System.out.println. que está justo después de crear el objeto recibo. Ahí es donde se queda pillado el programa.

Comment: Considero que es más probable que tengas problemas en el cliente que en el servidor. Es normal que se quede enganchado en el mensaje de "Esperando datagrama" ya que no avanzara hasta recibir algo. Procede a debugear el cliente y a asegurar que se manda correctamente el datagrama

Comment: Acabo de verlo! Qué error más tonto! En la clase servidor al crear el serverSocket le puse entre paréntesis el puerto de escucha como 9886. Mientras que en la clase cliente, el puerto destino donde envío el DatagramPacket le puse el 6000. Normal que no me saliese nada, es que directamente al servidor no le estaba llegando nada.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo visto la tarea que tenía que hacer era meter una sóla cadena con 4 números separados por un espacio. Y el programa hacer las operaciones y luego devolverme el resultado. O sea que la forma de plantear el ejercicio era distinta. Lo he modificado, ahora no se me para, pero me da un error que no entiendo bien. Los códigos son:

Para cliente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String cadena;      
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        byte[] listData = new byte[1024];       
        byte[] datosEnviados = new byte[1024];
        byte[] datosRecibidos = new byte[1024];


        InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.127"); 
        int puerto = 6000;        


        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Introduce 4 números separados por un espacio en blanco: ");
            cadena = in.readLine();


            listData = cadena.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(listData, listData.length, IPServidor, puerto);
            clientSocket.send(envio);           

            //recibimos respuesta del servidor
            DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(datosRecibidos, datosRecibidos.length);
            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");
            clientSocket.receive(recibo);
            String numero = new String(recibo.getData());                        
            if (numero.equals("x")) {
                break;           
            }        
            System.out.println("\t Datos: " + numero);      

        } //Fin While

        clientSocket.close(); //Cerramos cliente
    }

}
```

Para servidor:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(6000);
        byte[] infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
        byte[] infoEnviada = new byte[1024];
        byte[] paquete = new byte[1024];
        String cadena;
        List list;
        int n1,n2,n3,n4;
        int res;
        String num;
        String num1,num2,num3,num4;
        String x;


        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");            
            infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket paqRecibido = new DatagramPacket(infoRecibida, infoRecibida.length);
            serverSocket.receive(paqRecibido);     
            cadena = new String(paqRecibido.getData());

         // IP y puerto desde donde se manda mensaje
            InetAddress IPOrigen = paqRecibido.getAddress();
            int puerto = paqRecibido.getPort();


            String[] numeros = cadena.split(" ");
            n1 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
            n2 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
            n3 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[2]);
            n4 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[3]);

            num1= Integer.toString(n1);
            num2= Integer.toString(n2);
            num3= Integer.toString(n3);
            num4= Integer.toString(n4);

            // Si alguno de los números introducidos es * 
            // envío "x" al cliente para que este se cierre, posteriormente sale del bucle y se cierra también el servidor
            if (num1=="*"||num2=="*"||num3=="*"||num4=="*") {
                x = "x";
                paquete = x.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket paqueteFinal = new DatagramPacket(paquete, paquete.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
                break;
            }

            //Hago las operaciones, el resultado lo paso a cadena y luego a bytes, para ser enviado al cliente
            res=(n1+n2)*n3;
            num = Integer.toString(res);                      
            infoEnviada=num.getBytes();


            // ENVIO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE
            DatagramPacket paqEnviado = new DatagramPacket(infoEnviada, infoEnviada.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
            serverSocket.send(paqEnviado);

        } //Fin While


        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Socket cerrado...");

    }

}
```

El error que me marca es

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Servidor.main(Servidor.java:43)
```

Comment: es mi imaginacion o le pusiste explícitamente las comillas dentro de las comillas de tu cadena?